# shortcut to change main display while in extended mode

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, keyboard-shortcuts, external-display

I'm using a tablet as my second/extended monitor, I want to find a way to map a single hot key combination to one of my buttons, so whenever I toggle it, it changes my main display to the other monitor, so they swap places... that way I can always display the monitor I'm working on through my tablet at all times, as my pen can already be mapped to switch between displays.

options like Win+shift+< or > only move windows on a display, and Win+P only changes the display mode, but I don't want to switch the extended to a different mode like show 1 or 2 only, or duplicate, I want to keep the extended option, just switch the monitors without needing to go into settings, clicking on the other screen and scrolling down and checking "make this my main display", I need it to do that function automatically.

It seem ridiculous that after all these years windows doesn't have something so simple, but perhaps there's a program that can do it? I don't know anything about programing yet, so giving me a line of code won't do me any good without clear instruction on how to make it an exe that the mapping function could run.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need an application that can be used to save & load monitor layouts
and be called as a command-line.

One suitable application may be the free
[MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) :

> Save/Load Monitors Configuration
> MultiMonitorTool allows you to save the current configuration of all monitors on your system, including the screen resolution, colors depth, and monitor position of every monitor, by using the 'Save Monitors Configuration' option (Ctrl+Shift+S).
> You can restore back the saved monitors configuration by using the 'Load Monitors Configuration' option (Ctrl+Shift+L).
> You can also save/load the monitors configuration from command-line, by using the /SaveConfig and /LoadConfig command-line options.

After setting up and saving your two configurations,
create two `.bat` files for invoking MultiMonitorTool for each
configuration. You may create links to the files on the desktop,
then assign them keyboard shortcuts.